# simple way to invert logic

Tags: digital-logic, inverter

I need to feed a pair of logic inputs of a DG211 electronic switch with a single logic output from my 3.3V microcontroller.
The two logic inputs on the DG211 need to be one the opposite of the other.
So I can simply connect the microcontroller output to one of them, and then invert that signal to go to the other logic input.
How could I invert that signal without using a whole inverter IC?
would you use a single inverter IC (those that are made of SOT23 package for example) or a simple transistor and resistor would do it just fine?
the frequency of this logic signal is about 100KHz

note: of course I can't use an additional microcontroller output, and I'm aware of the existence of complementary NC/NO analog switch like DG413

edit/update: the PCB with DG211 doesn't have access to 3.3V supply, but only 5V supply. DG211 is fine with 3.3V logic level even if powered by 5V, but any additional IC would be supplied with 5V and not 3.3V

Comment: I think the most simple solution will be a little circuit with a NMOS transistor, by selecting one depending on the switching frequency.

Comment: Have you considered using a [DG213](https://www.vishay.com/docs/70662/dg213.pdf) instead, which contains both kinds of switches?

Comment: Could you just invert the signal in the microcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

A SOT23-5 Schmitt Trigger inverter like SN74LVC1G14DBVR might be smaller than some self made circuit.

However, if you need two of them, a multi port inverter will certainly be easier/smaller.

See also the comment of dim below.

Comment: I agree. I'd just replace "might" by "will certainly". And this will also consume less power than any circuit with a pullup. It may even be cheaper, if you account for the assembly costs. There really isn't any downsides to that.

Comment: Thanks for even more reasons. Updated my answer to look at your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot a really important detail (I updated the question). The SN74LVC1G14DBVR would be powered by 5V (because I don't have 3.3V supply on that PCB) and so it would not work correctly with 3.3V logic.

Comment: If you need multiple ports you can consider a 14 pins 74LVT14: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Philips%20Semiconductor%20PDFs/74LVT14.pdf

Comment: @DimitriPetrucci I recommend that you read the data sheet (table 6.5) for the SN74LVC1G14DBVR and not assume it wouldn't work.

Comment: SN74LVC1G14DBV, see http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g14.pdf  .. first page, section 3: This single Schmitt-trigger inverter is designed for 1.65-V to 5.5-V VCC operation.

Comment: should I look at the "VT+ Positivegoing input threshold voltage" spec? if yes, then it says the threshold is between 2.61V and 3.33V for 5.5V supply, so it would work using 5V supply and 3.3V logic. Am I right?

Comment: I'm almost sure you have to read it like this: you are using 3.3V (let's assume 3V since that's in the table): the threshold voltage will be between 1.5 and 1.87V. This means (forgive me if I'm wrong) that if the voltage goes up, and comes above 1.5-1.87V, a '1'/HIGH value is considered. When going down VT- is used (which is lower), thus it  prevents very fast changing between 0 and 1 in case there would be only one threshold value. This is probably the Schmitt Trigger functionality.